# Powerapps Multiple Screens from SharePoint Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Two questions:

1. In a SharePoint multiple screen form, how do you link the pages together in an edit? When I open an existing item, the first page shows the item selected but the other pages will either show blank or the first() item in the list.
2. Do I need to do three separate apps, one for view, edit and new? I've seen conflicting information from Microsoft with this, but haven't been able to really tell what I should be doing. I still have the problem above when doing it this way.

Thanks.